# Why doesn't angularJS directly give the specific error location, rather than giving a link to their website link which gives some generic explanation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, error-handling

Why doesn't angularJS directly throw the specific error location(i.e., in which file there is an error or fault), rather than giving a link their website link which gives some generic explanation? It is making debugging a very difficult task!

Whenever there is an error, i can't debug the app easily because I have to go  through the complete application and search every line, if it is valid line or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.log() in the module where you are debugging, might make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Because AngularJS is not being compiled so it can not know its exact location where actual error occurred.**

For example Suppose you are defining a module Say 'XYZ' as follows

```
angular.module('XYZ', []);
```

Then you are using this as

```
var app = angular.module('XYZ');
```

But if you did mistake and do as follows

```
var app = angular.module('XYZ', []);
```

AngularJS will think you want to override your previous module. Then angular can not found dependency for the old component which were defined earlier on 'XYZ' module. So angular will tell those component are not defined.

**One more point mostly those error happens on angular digest cycle which is not in our code.**

Another Example

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function() {
  $scope.foo = $scope.foo + 1;
});
```

The above code will be executed infinite time because foo is being watch if it is changed, and insde of watch it is again being changed.

But after 10 iteration angular will stop execution and show a link. Because angular does know it is a digest cycle repetition happening. But do not know which part of the code is responsible for that.

> Note: Yes, I found angularJS debugging is really little hard, But If
>   we see the error carefully and try to find out what latest changes we
>   did last time, then we can found exact problem.